# How to check the disposed paint object ?

Tags: xamarin, memory-leaks, xamarin.android, paint, dispose

I have checked the condition for disposed object by below code.

```
 if(paint.Handle != IntPtr.Zero)
  {
  // code
  }
```

My question is there any other way to check the disposed object apart from this?

Comment: Try use **Control.IsDisposed** : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isdisposed.aspx

Comment: The question is about Xamarin.Android not windows forms.